# Merge tags lease and leasing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Please merge the tags [lease](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lease) and [leasing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leasing).

Answer (score 8):

I propose a more complex operation.

The issue is that the tags [lease](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lease) and [leasing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leasing) have zero guidance becasue they are both trying to deal with vehicle-leasing and real-estate-leasing.

Those are two topics that shouldn't be combined. One involves issue such as maximum mileage, residual value, trade ins. The other has landlord-tenant issues, and security deposits.

As I write this of the 10 newest [lease](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lease) questions 5 are on apartments, the other 5 have to do with vehicles.

For the [leasing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leasing) 5 of the first 15 are about real-estate, 9 are about vehicles  An added complexity is that one of them is about leasing other equipment for a business.

Just combining the tags will not help becasue it will continue to mean that all the questions are jumbled together. Some questions currently have both tags. I believe that is because the taggers were happy with either existing tag.

**Proposal:**

Make two new tags

- one for auto-leasing and
- one for real-estate leasing.

Take all the questions in the two existing tags and put them in one of the new  tags.

Complete the tag Wiki entries for these new tags

Comment: Are you proposing we create 2 tags; vehicle-leasing and real-estate-leasing? If so agreed. We create the tags and move over the questions and then delete the old tags.

Comment: added proposal to answer.

Comment: The same thing occurred to me, but I thought it could be done in an independent operation even after we merge them.

Comment: Also, if we do this, we should blacklist the existing tags (lease/leasing), but I think that requires help from the StackExchange admins.

Comment: "leasing other equipment for a business" is easy to deal with -- business finance is off-topic

Comment: I think you can just go ahead and create the new tags and apply them, then we can figure out what to do with the existing tags.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I have just completed this. I have retained lease for generic questions not related to auto or real estate. However not able to create a tag synonym for lease as leasing.

Comment: @Dheer: Thanks! I have created the tag synonym.

Answer (score 1):

Seems an obvious one, but as it's hard to undo I'll leave this out there for a bit for comments first.

I propose that we keep [lease](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lease) as that's the more widely used one, although I'd actually marginally prefer [leasing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leasing) if it was an otherwise equal choice.